# Can't play video through intent

Tags: android, android-intent, video, apk-expansion-files

My app has a photo gallery that displays a constant list of images. I need to add one **video** to that list (just one, provided by me). This video is inside an **expansion file**. I would like to let the user decide the video player he wants to use to play the video. So I went for the **intent** approach:

```
public void playVideo(View view){
    Intent videoint = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri uri = CustomAPEZProvider.buildUri("test.3gp");
    Log.d("TEST", uri.toString());
    videoint.setDataAndType(uri, "video/*");
    startActivity(videoint);
}
```

My `CustomAPEZProvider` is the following:

```
public class CustomAPEZProvider extends APEZProvider {
    private static final String AUTHORITY = "com.myapp.package.provider";

    @Override
    public String getAuthority() {
        return AUTHORITY;
    }

    public static Uri buildUri(String path) {
        StringBuilder contentPath = new StringBuilder("content://");
        contentPath.append(AUTHORITY);
        contentPath.append(File.separator);
        contentPath.append(path);
        return Uri.parse(contentPath.toString());
    }
}
```

Also, I added this to my manifest:

```
<provider android:name="com.myapp.package.CustomAPEZProvider"
    android:authorities="com.myapp.package.provider" >
    android:exported="true"
    android:multiprocess="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="mainVersion"
        android:value="4"/>
</provider>
```

The `provider` has this `meta-data` because the expansion file version differs from the apps version code.

I understand that the file is being found, but the video players are not able to play it. **They are launching the *can't play this video* window** (and no errors). I tested it on many devices and with different kinds of videos. The 3gp video I'm using to test can be played just fine from the phone's native gallery.

Line 3 on the `playVideo` method is printing this

> content://com.myapp.package.provider/test.3gp

This is correct, right?

The expansion file has no folders, files are just thrown at root.

Also, I actually need to play this `test.3gp` video from the **patch** expansion file. Will there be any difference in that case? I'm eliminating this obstacle for now. I know I should add it to the provider's meta-data.

Some extra information: the expansion file has several audio files that I'm being able to play using a `MediaPlayer` without any issues. Of course, this is different because in that case I'm doing it by getting an `AssetFileDescriptor` to the file inside the obb expansion file, whereas with the video I need an `Uri`, which changes everything.

I read lots of questions with similar problems, but they were not helpful. Does anyone had the same problem?

Workarounds are also welcome. For example, I could accept to use a `VideoView` if needed.

**UPDATE**

I've just realised that the video player is not working, even if the file is a resource (inside drawable, raw, or whatever). I did manage to play the video with the code below:

```
public void playVideo(View view){
    Uri uri = CustomAPEZProvider.buildUri("test.3gp");
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    videoHolder.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    videoHolder.setVideoURI(uri);
    setContentView(videoHolder);
    videoHolder.start();
}
```

But this is not exactly what I want, I'd really like to allow the user to choose the video player of his preference. Mainly because I want to free myself from the responsibility to code a nice-to-look-at video player.

Comment: got similar "cant play this video" dialog with no errors except iam storing a video in the public downloads file? not sure why it wont play?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the problem lies anywhere in your code.  Or, if it does, it's not your biggest problem.

I think your biggest problem is using a 3GP file.  That format is not supported by all devices.  You're better off with an MP4.  And even then, make sure that it's encoded with a CODEC that all Android devices understand.

Comment: But what about this (I quote myself)? *The 3gp video I'm using to test can be played just fine from the phone's native gallery.*

I'm also testing with an mp4 file, and I'm having the same issue.

Comment: i have a  mp4 file. can play from the downloads file when i navigate to it manually?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (video played without problem with native gallery, but not through intent). How the problem is solved is to add the following line to manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and give the permission to the installed app.